# Memory leak from creation of MutationObserver in Custom Element constructor?

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, web-component, custom-element

I've got a Custom Element class that creates a mutation observer in it's createdCallback. At no point is `observer.disconnect()` ever called. Will this cause a memory leak? If so, how would you recommend handling it?

Here's a basic example:

```
class SomeElement extends HTMLElement {
    createdCallback() {
        // Observe nodes in the future.
        const observer = new MutationObserver(changes => {
            for (let change of changes) {
                if (change.type != 'childList') continue

                for (let node of change.addedNodes)
                    this.childConnectedCallback(node)

                for (let node of change.removedNodes)
                    this.childDisconnectedCallback(node)
            }
        })
        observer.observe(this, { childList: true })
    }

    childConnectedCallback(node) {
        // ...
    }

    childDisconnectedCallback(node) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the Garbage Collector is well designed it shouldn't have memory leaks. The mutation observer will be disposed when the custom element is itself deleted.

Anyway you can always call `observer.disconnect()` in the `detachedCallback()` method. In this case use `this.observer` instead of `const observer` to keep the reference.

Comment: For some reason ( I don't remember at the moment) calling `disconnect` was not feasible in my case, which is why I asked. Well, I hope the JS engine can be smart enough...